# Using Python to click "Download as csv" button

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to create a script that automates the process of clicking a "download as CSV" file on a website. Here is an [example](https://www.draftkings.com/contest/gamecenter/90543300#/) of a csv I want to download (near the bottom of the page there is a download button). I double clicked the button and hit inspect element on chrome and got the link that downloads the csv file:

```
https://www.draftkings.com/contest/exportfullstandingscsv/90543300
```

How can I read this link into a pandas dataframe? `.read_csv()` doesn't work since we have the link that gets the csv and not the csv itself, and trying `.read_html()` returns an error that no tables are found.

Again, I am trying to use python to automate the process of clicking the download as csv button. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A "click" is just a HTTP GET request. What issues are you having pulling only that URL from the webpage and making a new request to it?

Comment: Ahh, okay. So I would have to `import requests` and then call `requests.get()`? I will try that.

Comment: Right, after using regex or preferably HTML parser to get to that element

Comment: You cannot parse HTML with regex. Use an HTML parser. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/447901

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is to perform a GET request on the given URL. You can use Python's `requests` library to achieve that:

```
import requests

url = 'your/url/here'
r = requests.get(url)

# you can then read the contents using `r.contents`
```